# How do you start a python code using keyboard

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, clipboard

Is there a way to start a python code automatically when a set of keyboard presses are made?

context:
I want to be able to hit control v (or any other custom key binds) inside a specific folder and the script will run which will result in the picture that I have stored in my clipboard will be automatically made to a jpg.

this is the script that I am using to convert the picture in my clipboard to a png

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from datetime import datetime
import os

 
im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
date_now = datetime.now().strftime('%c')
im.save(f'{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/{str(date_now)}.png','PNG')
```

P.S. this is because I am tired of getting a screenshot and then needing to open paint to just image and saving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using another python script that runs all the time:

```
$pip install keyboard
```

```py
import keyboard as k
import os

# function to run your python script after keyboard shortcut
def run_script(path_to_file):
  os.system("cmd /k python " + path_to_file)

#add hot key for you shortcut
k.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+a', run_script, args=["enter your path to file here"])
k.wait()
```

Or else if you are using Windows, create a shortcut for your python script (right click it and then `"Create shortcut"`), right click the shortcut file you just created and click `"Properties"`, then go to the `"Shortcut`" tab and click the `"Shortcut key:"` box, and finally type the combination that you want. if it seems like its not working, than its probably because the python file has no wait on the end of it, so it executes but then immediately closes.

Comment: oh wow! i forgot that windows 10 has a built in functionality wherein you can just put a hotkey for a shortcut. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i think this is related to the operating system or window manager you use. For example: in XFCE you'll find it under applications / settings / keyboard / shortcuts. (or something like that.. my desktop is held in German language..)

under Windows you can make a desktop link to your software. When you edit it you can set a shortcut for running this, too.

try to ask google for something like
[your os] shortcut for program